# How to Autologout after 30 secounds of inactivity of Account

Tags: php

Help me please how to autologout after 30 secounds of inactivity of php site . my default index.php  and login.php code is

```
@setcookie("abcd_script", $_SESSION['private'], time() + (60 * 15));
@header("location: index.php");
```

Please help me how to change into this autologout after 30 secounds inactivity of account ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? How is the given code related to your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

It only can be done with Javascript:

```
var timer = setTimeout( () => {
    window.location.href = '/logout.php';

    //if you want to delete any cookie
    document.cookie = "cookiename= ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    //replace cookiename to name of cookie which you want tot delete

}, 30000);//30 seconds = 30000 milliseconds
```

At any time if you want to clear timeout you can write this code to any event or just anywhere...

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear boss i am using this autologout javascript code in my index.php which is showing in the screenshot and also i m using this code in login.php

```
@setcookie("abcd_script", $_SESSION['private'], time() + (60 * 15));
@header("location: index.php");
```

and i dont have logout.php page it  will redirects to the login page after autologout by using that javascript code .I wanna change this code into autologout after 30 seconds..